# manytomany fields not visible in _meta.fields

Tags: django

I have a generic function that iterates over _meta.fields of a given object. All field names and values are fetched correctly except for ManyToMany fields. It seems to completely ignore ManyToMany fields. How do we retrive the fks from m2m fields?

```
def myfunc(self)
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        type = field.get_internal_type()
        name = field.name
        val = getattr(self,field.name)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are in `self._meta.many_to_many`

Comment: From the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/options/#Options) for the `_meta.many_to_many` property: "*Private API* intended only to be used by Django itself; `get_fields()` combined with filtering of field properties is the *public API* for obtaining this list."

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get all field names in a model. You don't need to use `self._meta.many_to_many + self._meta.fields`.

You can just use `[field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]`.

Note that `get_fields` will return all fields(including many-to-many and foreign key)

> Django get_fields:

```
def get_fields(self, include_parents=True, include_hidden=False):
    """
    Returns a list of fields associated to the model. By default, includes
    forward and reverse fields, fields derived from inheritance, but not
    hidden fields. The returned fields can be changed using the parameters:

    - include_parents: include fields derived from inheritance
    - include_hidden:  include fields that have a related_name that
                       starts with a "+"
    """
```