# ManyToManyField is not displayed in the Python shell

Tags: python, mysql, django, shell

I am learning how to work with mysql database,using Django.
I've created models in myapp.models. I've added ManyToManyField to my model. I've applied the changes made to these models, using *makemigrations and migrate*. All processes have been going OK.

However, this ManyToManyField is not displayed in Python shell when I type the command:

```
>>> Employer._meta.fields
```

Employer is the name of my model. And I want to print all Fields of this model in the terminal.

When I type this command, I get Employer's fields printed in the terminal except for this ManyToManyFiled. Could you explain why?

```
(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: employees>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: name>, <django.db.models.fields.DateField: foundation_date>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manytomany fields not visible in \_meta.fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572871/manytomany-fields-not-visible-in-meta-fields)

Comment: @Bear Brown the answers according to your link do not help me with the question "Why is ManyToManyField not displayed in the Python shell". So it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

as a best practice and getting solid understanding of how django ORM works and in debugging situations try to execute your codes in python shell with virtualenv activated by running:

```
(e3.5)  ⚙ user@ubuntu djangoproject$ python manage.py shell
```

in order to get objects from the Employer's model import it to the shell like so :

```
>>> from company.models import Employer
```

make a instance of the model and try to get a employer object:

```
>>> emp = Employer.objects.get(id=1)
```

now you can call any column of the instance like so:

```
>>> emp.name
>>> 'Jackson'
```

for ManyToManyFields relations that are assigned to your object you can call them :

```
>>> emp.tags.all()
<QuerySet [<Tag: computer>, <Tag: science>, <Tag: web>]>
```

as you can see by calling the a ManyToManyField you'll get a queryset that includes all the **tags** are references to; and you can

- loop through them them
- filtering the queries
- getting the single specific tag

in the reverse side you can get **Employers** that are specified with a **tag** like so:

```
>>> from company.models import Tag
>>> b = Tag.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b
<Tag: computer>
>>> b.Employer_set
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f0a02bbceb8>
>>> b.Employer_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Employer: Jackson>]>
b.Employer_set.get(id=1)
<Employer: Jackson>
```